# Timer on Mouse Down in c#

Tags: c#, timer, mousedown

So I want to know for how long the user presses down on a button. I am using the button1_MouseDown method as you can see below. However  the count variable is staying 0.

Can someone please help me solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

```
    private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(MusKey mk in this.Controls)     
        {
            if(sender == mk)
            {
                if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                {
                    timer1.Enabled = true;
                    count = 0;
                    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
                    timer1.Start();
                    sp.SoundLocation = ( ---directory---- + mk.musicNote + ".wav");
                    sp.Play();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count = count++;
    }
```

Comment: does your timer1_tick runs?, i think your event handler should be in the load method, you dont need to rebind every time u click it

Comment: So you are saying that I don't need the timer1_Tick eevnt handler? and I should put count++ in the load method?

Comment: Don't use a timer. Save the timestamp, when the MouseDown happens, then calculate duration in MouseUp event.

Comment: no i am saying  timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick); should be in the load method

Comment: Also, you better check for MouseButton.Left first, so you don't need to traverse a datastructure just to realize you don't actually care.

Comment: are you using wpf? theres an event to detect a left mouse down MouseLeftButtonDown

Comment: I am using windows forms. thanks for your help. I did a mistake on count ++ but now i arranged it thanks to @PaulF

Comment: And it's better to use StopWatch not timer. Just start on MouseDown and check on MouseUp. More precise and uses less resources.

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev You don't even need a stopwatch. Just save DateTime.Now somwhere and calculate duration in MouseUp.

Comment: @Fildor MS doesn't recommend to use DateTime.Now for measuring intervals.

Comment: I agree with you @Alander that the timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick); should be in the load method –

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev I am sure they also wouldn't recommend OP's design ... In this case its resolution should suffice. Of course you wouldn't want to use it for a performance benchmark where you need small ms precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is due to the assignment using a post increment.

```
count = count++;
```

The order of events is to evaluate the right hand side including side effects before the assignment - so the current value of count is stored (=0) count is then incremented & now the stored value is assigned - the original value of zero is being written back over the incremented value.

You only need to use count++;

```
private void timer1_Tick (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. It was a stupid mistake from my end.

Comment: Happens to us all & sometimes they are the hardest problems to find.

Comment: @KurtCamilleri It's worth saying that this overall design is pretty fragile anyway. But this answer should at least solve your problem.